# Динамическое меню в django 2

Tags: django, menu, django-admin

Добрый день начал изучать Django 2. До этого имел начальные знания с ModX revo. Суть вопроса состоит в том как реализовать меню навигации, так чтобы его можно было редактировать с админки, а не править код. Все это в целях повышения знаний для реализации потом в проекте. Или это противоречит сути джанго? Или стоит указывать в ссылках просто урлы без хардкода? Спасибо заранее за ответ

Comment: Создать модель для пунктов меню, потом в шаблоне генерировать html-код согласно данным из этой модели, а в админке редактировать её. Учебники по Django читали?

Answer (score 1):

Меню это древовидная структура, используй django-mptt или django-treebeard